# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de llenar un spinner con sqlite?

Tags: android

he tenido problemas con el spinner por que el metodo setSeletion() no trabaja, desconosco las razones en si, pèro creo que es por la forma de popularlo, por eso recurro a ustedes para que me den ideas, para eso ya he utilizado varios metodos, cual seria la forma correcta de trabajar con los spinner, desde llenar hasta consultar un valor previamente guardado,

Este mi codigo para cargar el spinner nada de lo ordinario:

```
public void SPPersona(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String qryTP = "select _id, Tipo_persona from TB_Tipo_persona";
    Cursor cTP = db.rawQuery(qryTP,null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cTPA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  cTP, new String[] {"Tipo_persona"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1} );
    cTPA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sptipper.setAdapter(cTPA);
    }
```

Este otro es para consultar:

```
private void consulta(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String mqry = "select * from Creditos_productores where _id = " + id;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(mqry,null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int tp = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id_tipo")));
       sptipper.setSelection(tp);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar lo que has intentado y asi poder ayudarte.

Comment: haber amigo que puede ser

Comment: Podrían por favor colocar todo el código completo se como se selecciona el spinner y como se guarda en la Base de Datos de SQLite. Agradeceria su colaboracion.

Comment: ya lo esta resuelto el problema amigo muchas gracias.....

Answer (score -1):

Buenos señores tantas horas de ver que era y resulta que es a la hora de cargar las funciones o metodos que utilicen osea en el OnCreate() se van cargando todas las funciones que primero debe sersiorarse de que carguen el spinner con datos y despues hacer la consulta. osea de la siguiente forma:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sulayout);
    cargaSpinner();
    consultaDatos();
}


consultaDatos(){
//Cualquier forma de consultar datos////
}

cargaSpinner{}{
//Cualquier forma de cargar el spinner
}
```

Sale buen dia gracias a todos aquellos colegas que se prestan y se toman el tiempo para ayudarte espero que con este aporte le sea de mucha ayuda